# Media query is not working

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a html file, with this line of code:

```
<link href="media-queries.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

And a media query file with:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 1224px) {

    * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    body { font: 14px Georgia, serif; }


    #header { background: #eee; padding: 10px;  position: fixed; width:100%; border: 1px solid #999;}
    #wrapper { border: 1px solid #999;  color: black; position:absolute; top: 100px; }
    #left-menu{ background: #eee; float:left;}

}
```

and few more resolutions.
My screen resolution is higher than 1224px, so it should take this part of css, but it doesn't. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

**I just finished reading media query articles 5 minutes ago, so maybe I skipped something and I can't figure out what I did wrong.**

Comment: Maybe try..  @media (max-width: 1224px)

Comment: Note that the width of the browser window is what matters here, NOT your screen resolution.

Comment: The CSS file is definitely been loaded?

Comment: @BryanDowning the width of my browser is also higher than 1224px

Comment: @3rror404 , yes im sure its loaded

Comment: It's impossible. The only think that comes to my mind is that mediaqueries are included and/or writting in a wrong order. Can you share the order of the mediaqueries and the code without mediaqueries?